# Is there any build in function for making 2D tensor from 1D tensor using specific calculation?

Tags: pytorch

Hi I'm student who just started for deep learning.

For example, I have 1-D tensor `x = [ 1 , 2]`. From this one, I hope to make 2D tensor `y` whose `(i,j)`th element has value `(x[i] - x[j])`, i.e `y[0,:] = [0  ,  1]` , `y[1,:]=[ -1 , 0]`.

Is there built-in function like this in pytorch library?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question contradicts itself. If `y[i,j] = x[i] - x[j]` then `y[0,:] = [0, -1]` and `y[1,:] = [1, 0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you need right dim of tensor to get expected result which you can get using [`torch.unsqueeze`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.unsqueeze)

```py
x = torch.tensor([1 , 2])
y = x - x.unsqueeze(1)
y
tensor([[ 0,  1],
        [-1,  0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you could get this result, the cleanest I can think of is using [broadcasting semantics](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html).

```
x = torch.tensor([1, 2])
y = x.view(-1, 1) - x.view(1, -1)
```

which produces

```
y = tensor([[0, -1],
            [1,  0]])
```

---

*Note* I'll try to edit this answer and remove this note if the original question is clarified.

In your question you ask for `y[i, j] = x[i] - x[j]`, which the above code produces.

You also say that you expect `y` to have values

```
y = tensor([[ 0, 1],
            [-1, 0]])
```

which is actually `y[i, j] = x[j] - x[i]` as was posted in Dishin's answer. If you instead wanted the latter then you can use

```
y = x.view(1, -1) - x.view(-1, 1)
```

Comment: Actually I need to do more practice about basic tensor calculation. Thanks a lot :-)